# Ansible Playbook to install nginx server

Tags: python, nginx, ansible, devops

I want to install nginx in ubuntu machine and start the service using Ansible playbook,

I am getting this error while running playbook "(): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 7 column 10"

Here is the code I tried:

```
--- 
- 
  hosts: all
  tasks: 
    - name: ensure nginx is at the latest version
      apt: name=nginx state=latest
    - name: "start nginx"
      service: 
        name: nginx
        state: started
```

Answer (score 7):

So, I spotted a typo in there with `name:ensure`, you really need the space.

Also, you should name your playbooks, and maybe avoid inlining when it's not necessary/simpler (apt: name=nginx state=latest).

Additionally, you could have a look at using full named for the modules (`service` -> `ansible.builtin.service`).

```yaml
--- 
- name: set up webserver
  hosts: all
  tasks: 
    - name: ensure nginx is at the latest version
      apt:
        name: nginx
        state: latest
    - name: start nginx
      service: 
        name: nginx
        state: started
        enabled: yes  # if you want to also enable nginx
```